# Does babel produce only ES5 code?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

If I use Babel, does that mean, I'm essentially taking all the ES6 code I've typed out, and transpile it into ES5 code? This sounds like an obvious point, but I asking because the implications are a bit dramatic.

If this is the case, then my project will only produce ES5 code, even for browsers that support ES6,... right?

In which case, what am I supposed to do, go in and change my build process in a few years?

Comment: Yes, in a few years you can remove the Babel step.

Comment: We can only speculate about the future but I presume that Babel will eventually change the default target version and you'll only need for ES2020XP code.

Comment: Yes, and removing Babel is a thing of 1min or so. Its not like you have to change a big part of your build-process

Comment: You can configure Babel to do anything you want, transpile only some parts of ES6 to ES5, or you can use it to transpile ES8 to ES6, etc…